# MySQL find previous episode in serial?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @current_episode = 1;
SET @current_season = 2;
SET @current_serial = 2;

SELECT * FROM `episode` _episode 
    LEFT JOIN season _season ON _episode.season_id = _season.id
    LEFT JOIN serial _serial ON _season.serial_id  = _serial.id 
WHERE 

    (_episode.episode < @current_episode AND _season.season = @current_season)
        OR 
    (_episode.episode > @current_episode AND _season.season = (@current_season - 1))

ORDER BY _season.season DESC, _episode.episode ASC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Episode table structure:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| season_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                              |
| poster_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| episode     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                              |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Season table structure:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| serial_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| season     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

Serial table structure:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

My SQL cannot be found previous episode correctly
Because if I try found it by season DESC it will be corrent while episode number is not first episode of season.

Comment: Aliases that are longer than the identifiers they replace? Brilliant.

Comment: This is done for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Find previous episode

Just update `WHERE` clause after `OR` and sort `DESC` on _episode.episode as well

```
SET @current_episode = 1;
SET @current_season = 2;
SET @current_serial = 2;

SELECT * FROM `episode` _episode 
    LEFT JOIN season _season ON _episode.season_id = _season.id
    LEFT JOIN serial _serial ON _season.serial_id  = _serial.id 
WHERE 

    (_episode.episode < @current_episode AND _season.season = @current_season)
        OR 
    (_season.season < @current_season)

ORDER BY _season.season DESC, _episode.episode DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```